# Condition list with a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, conditional-statements

That code is working but I am thinking that should use a for loop instead of the condition list.
Has someone have an idea about how i could make the code "lighter"?

````
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('vin_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('cremant_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('biere_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('cidre_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('pastis_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('whisky_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('bourbon_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('brandy_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('tequila_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('vodka_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('gin_')),
                 (df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains('rhum_')),
                ]

choicelist = ['champagne','vin','cremant','biere','cidre', 'pastis','whisky',
             'bourbon','brandy',"tequila","vodka","gin", "rhum"]

df_only_total_sales['Product_type']= np.select(conditionlist, choicelist, default="?" ) 


df_only_total_sales.sample(10)```


Using a for loop instead, i got the following error: first argument must be string or compiled pattern


```choicelist = ['champagne','vin','cremant','biere','cidre', 'pastis','whisky',
             'biurbon','brandy',"tequila","vodka","gin", "rhum"]

for i in range(0,len(choicelist)):
    conditionlist = [(df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains(i))]
    
    
df_only_total_sales['Product_type']= np.select(conditionlist, choicelist, default="?" ) 


df_only_total_sales.sample(10)```
````

Comment: FYI - You are overwriting `conditionlist` with every iteration because it is inside your for-loop Try doing something like `conditionlist = [(df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains(i)) for i in choicelist]` instead

Comment: Also, you are iterating over a range, so `i` will take values 0, 1, ... not the values from `choicelist`. You can do instead `for choice in choicelist:`

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you're checking if your string contains integers rather than strings.  To solve that, you could check that `choicelist[i]` rather than `i` is contained, but you could also write something even cleaner:

```
# DO NOT USE, STILL HAS AN ERROR
for c in choicelist:
    conditionlist = [(df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains(c))]
```

That only fixes the runtime error, not the logic--there's another problem.  `conditionlist` is created again every time through the loop.  To solve that, you could create it beforehand and then append to it:

```
conditionlist = []
for c in choicelist:
    conditionlist.append(df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains(c))
```

Even more pythonic would be to use a list comprehension:

```
conditionlist = [df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains(c) for c in choicelist]
```

Comment: But then i can't watch, where there is a True..

Comment: conditionlist[conditionlist[0]==True] . I still have an error : list indices must be integers or slices, not Series.

Answer (score 0):

thank again. I find a way to get the number of item that if found for each elements of the choicelist:

```
choicelist = ['champagne','pinot','riesling','cremant']

conditionlist = [df_only_total_sales['post_name'].str.contains(c) for c in choicelist]
conditionlist

print("Produits disponibles (liste non-exhaustive, à compléter)")
somme_vrai  = []
for i in range(0,len(conditionlist)):
    somme_vrai = conditionlist[i].sum()
    somme_nom = choicelist[i]
    print(somme_nom, ":", somme_vrai,)
```